# Access Runtime Linked Table Query Date Format

Tags: sql, date, ms-access, runtime

I have the following query executed on a Linked table in Access:

**Select * From table WHERE DateField = #18-Dec-2016#**

This date where clause is created with the following VBA code:

**strWHERE = strWHERE & "DateField = #" & VBA.Format(txtDate, "dd-mmm-yyyy") & "#"**

When using the full version of Access 2016 it it sent to SQL as:

**Select * From table WHERE DateField = {d 18-Dec-2016}**

This works! However, when using the Access 2016 runtime, it is sent to SQL as:

**Select * From table WHERE DateField = {ts 18-Dec-2016}**

and it fails.

I am using SQL Server Profiler to find the exact SQL being sent.

Any ideas?

EDITS:

Tried changing format to yyyy-mm-dd

Tried added "00:00:00" to the VBA code building the where clause, and this does not change what I see sent to SQL through the profiler.

SOLVED:

For some reason, the behaviour of linked table queries is different between the full version of Access and the 2016 Runtime.

In the Runtime version, the data type of the field in the linked table is used to format the query. So because the DateField was DateTime, it passed the where clause as ts. BY creating a view and formatting the date as just a date, this was solved.

Comment: why don't you use "yyyy-mm-dd"? It is more foolproof.

Comment: It doesn't matter how I format the date, it is still sent incorrectly from Runtime.

Comment: {ts } is a timestamp format. If it wants it convert your format to this: VBA.Format(txtDate, "yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00"). More info [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190234(v=sql.90).aspx)

Comment: Tried, doesn't work. It strips the time section by the time I see it in profiler

Comment: You can always use the SQL server explicit type conversion by using `strWHERE = strWHERE & "DateField = '" & VBA.Format(txtDate, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "'"`

Comment: In fact, you can even use `strWHERE = strWHERE & "DateField = {d '" & VBA.Format(txtDate, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "'}"`

Comment: It's a linked table query, so the query itself needs to work in Access Query Editor. Access manages how that query is then translated for SQL, which is the problem.